# How to add an property to an existing object inside an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

**For example this is the original array**

```
[
 {name:xyz,id:123 },
 {name:abc,id:232},
]
```

**Now here is an another array**

```
[
 {value:'anything'},
 {value:'anything12312'}
]
```

**Now in new array or original array the output should be this**

```
[
 {value:'anything',name:xyz,id:123},
 {value:'anything12312', name:abc,id:232}}
]
```

**How can I achieve this**

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this ??

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),index and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as :

```js
let a = [
 {name:"xyz",id:123 },
 {name:"abc",id:232},
]

let b = [
 {value:'anyrhing'},
 {value:'anything12312'}
]

let res = a.map((el,idx)=> ({...el,...b[idx]}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use object destructuring.

```js
const arr1 = [
 {name:'xyz',id:123 },
 {name:'abc',id:232},
] 

const arr2 = [
 {value:'anyrhing'},
 {value:'anything12312'}
]

const arr3 = [];
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
  arr3.push({...arr2[i],...arr1[i]});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1=[
    {name:"xyz",id:123 },
    {name:"abc",id:232},
   ];
A2=[
    {value:'anyrhing'},
    {value:'anything12312'}
   ];

obj1={
    ...A2[0],
    ...A1[0]}

//another method to merge objects

obj2=Object.assign(A2[1],A1[1]);

//The result you needed

A3=[obj1,obj2];
```

Comment: please explain your code and don't just post it as an answer so the author of the question will understand it better